# sudo apt-get update checking for packages

Tags: apt

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

These two lines. It's getting the php5 package.

The first line supposedly to check for dependency.

But how does it knows this is for php package instead of for others or it just check for all Debian packages? And which website does it check against?

Answer (score 1):

It updates the package information for all repositories defined in [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)